# A2billing Readout Balance

Tags: asterisk, voip, agi

I am attempting to use A2billing to readout the balance of customers. To do this, I created a second agi-conf and set:

*Say Balance After Auth* to *Yes*, so I suppose the system should say the balance after the PIN is entered, however this does not happen. The system simply repeats asking for the PIN.
My extensions is as:

```
[balance]
exten => 120,1,AGI(a2billing.php,2)
exten => 120,n,Hangup()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At your admin web your should change acgi-conf2(in admin->config section) and change param to say balance after auth=yes.

Also you need ensure you have play_audio =yes and answer_call=yes

As option can be no files in /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en (that mean you have not correct install and very likly need correct reinstall of system).

If you still not got correct behavour, you have enable debug and see what a2billing write or hire expert.